# AutoHotKey pixel color comparison never yields true

Tags: autohotkey

I am comparing the color of a button on the screen to see if it turned to blue from gray and if it did, just click on it.

Here is my code snippet:

```
  pixelgetcolor c,%x1%,%y1%
  msgbox %c%
  ifequal, c, COLOR ; word COLOR is a place holder here .please see below for what I tried in place 
  {
    mousemove,%x1%,%y1%
    mouseclick,l
  }
```

In the `msgbox` output, I can see the color as `254ADD` and here is what I tried in place of the word COLOR above

```
254ADD
"254ADD"
COL=254ADD  then 
   %COL%
   COL
   "COL"
   "%COL%"
```

in none of these cases, my IfEqual line yielded a "true" and clicked on the button.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I did not try in place of the word COLOR was 0x254ADD, which miraculously worked.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the color should be returned as BGR (blue-green-red) `0x` prefixed uppercase hexadecimal.
If your msgbox really showed `254ADD` instead of `0x254ADD`, I don't really know what to say. That shouldn't happen. Maybe you're on some old AHK version that behaves weirdly or something.

But anyway, now about the usage of [`IfEqual`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfEqual.htm). I don't think you could've possible found a more legacy AHK command. This is like true 2005 level. Please switch over to a non deprecated modern [`if()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) statement.
But anyway, what you're now trying to do it compare the value, which the variable `c` holds, to the **literal text** `254ADD`.
And of course this will never be true. A number will not equal to some text.
If you add the `0x` prefix, then AHK knows you're referring to [a number](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Concepts.htm#numbers), a hexadecimal one. Then you're comparing a number to a number. Now there's at least a chance of your of your if statement yielding true.

So, these would be the two ways you could do it:

```
IfEqual, c, 0x254ADD ;in hex
IfEqual, c, 2443997 ;in dec
```

But please, get rid of the super deprecated legacy command, and overall, maybe consider switching over to using the new, and superior, expression syntax.
Here's all your code in non legacy stuff:

```
PixelGetColor, c, % x1, % y1
MsgBox, % c
if (c = 0x254ADD)
{
    MouseMove, % x1, % y1
    Click
}
```

Here's a good documentation page to get started with learning the difference between legacy syntax and expression syntax:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm